# c# Regex on XML string handler

Tags: c#, xml, regex, silverlight

Trying to fiddle around with regex here, my first attempt.
Im trying to extract some figures out of content from an XML tag. The content looks like this:

www.blahblah.se/maps.aspx?isAlert=true&lat=51.958855252721&lon=-0.517657021473527

I need to extract the lat and long numerical vales out of each link. They will always be the same amount of characters, and the lon may or may not have a "-" sign.

I thought about doing it like this below (its obviously not right though): (The string in question is in the "link" tag):

```
             var document = XDocument.Load(e.Result);
             if (document.Root == null)
             return;

            var events = from ev in document.Descendants("item1")
                     select new
                     {
                         Title = (ev.Element("title").Value),
                         Latitude = Regex.xxxxxxx(ev.Element("link").Value, @"lat=(?<Lat>[+-]?\d*\.\d*)", String.Empty),
                         Longitude = Convert.ToDouble(ev.Element("link").Value),

                     };

        foreach (var ev in events)
        {
 do stuff
  }
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Regex.Match(ev.Element("link").Value, @"lat=(?<Lat>[+-]?\d*\.\d*)").Groups[1].Value
```

Example:

```
string ev = "www.blahblah.se/maps.aspx?isAlert=true&lat=51.958855252721&lon=-0.517657021473527";
string s = Regex.Match(ev, @"lat=(?<Lat>[+-]?\d*\.\d*)").Groups[1].Value;
```

Result:

```
"51.958855252721"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a URL with GET parameters, I would be tempted to find a library that can pull that apart for you, rather than using regexps. There may be edge cases that your regexp doesn't handle, but a library built for the specific purpose would handle (it depends on the set of data that you have to parse and how well-bounded it is, of course).

Comment: Hi Brian, unfortunately I just have access to those links with that embedded data I need.